# How to write multi-line command in heroku procfile

Tags: bash, shell, heroku, command-line, procfile

I have a long command line in heroku procfile and want to break it into multiple lines.

Using backslash like below didn't help...

Procfile:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT\ 
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12\ 
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=$SOAP_SSL_KEYSTORE_PATH\ 
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=$SOAP_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD\ 
 $JAVA_OPTS -jar pwr-mobile-rest-api-jar/target/pwr-mobile-rest-api-jar-runnable.jar
```

How can I format the procfile for better looking?

Answer (score 1):

It works

```
echo \
hello world
```

It doesnt work

```
echo\
hello world
```

Put space before backslash and it should work.

Comment: This does not work for me